# Related to DDNS and Port Forwarding

Tags: port-forwarding, ddns

I have seen DDNS and Port Forwarding both in my router.

My router gets different IP addresses. Dynamic DNS is enabled.

- In which case we use DDNS and in which case we use Port Forwarding?
- Are there any similarities between both?
- Are both related to each other?

While configuring DDNS, I have seen following fields.

- Service
- Service Port
- Host Name
- Domain
- Username
- Password

In Service, there are ten services. One of them is http://freedns.afraid.org/. I don’t know what is it and how to use it.

However, I signed up http://freedns.afraid.org/.

How to configure DDNS and what details I need to fill in above fields?

With Regards

UGN

Answer (score 3):

> In which case we use DDNS and in which case we use Port Forwarding?

You want to forward ports to the internet (i.e. allow connections from the outside to reach a host inside your network)? **Port Forwarding**.

You want to be able to a service inside your network that is changing IP addresses fairly often? **DDNS (Dynamic DNS)**.

> Are there any similarities between both?

No they are two completely different and independent things.

> Are both related to each other?

In a sense, yes. You can use DDNS to be able to connect to your network without checking the IP address every day.

> How to configure DDNS and what details I need to fill in above fields?

- Service: select the service you use.
- Service Port: select the port the service uses, weird setting, probably HTTP (80) or HTTPS (443).
- Host Name: your host name, typically the thing before the domain
- Domain: the domain, typically `<ddns provider>.<tld>` (substitute the terms as needed, TLD means top-level domain like .com, .org etc)
- Username: self-explanatory
- Password: see above